# return dentro do controle não envia para o maproute certo

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Boa tarde, estou tentando utilizar o maproute para controlar edição e inserção de dados na tabela, atualmente meu routeConfig está assim:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        /*Sub Categoria*/
        routes.MapRouteWithName(
             name: "Editar Subcategoria", // Route name
             url: "CanaisDigitais/Subcategoria/Edit/{id}/{idp}",
             defaults: new { controller = "CanaisDigitais", action = "EditSub", id = UrlParameter.Optional, idp = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
        routes.MapRouteWithName(
              name: "Deletar Subcategoria", // Route name
              url: "CanaisDigitais/Subcategoria/Delete/{id}/{idp}",
              defaults: new { controller = "CanaisDigitais", action = "DeleteSub", id = UrlParameter.Optional, idp = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
        routes.MapRouteWithName(
            name: "Subcategoria", // Route name
            url: "CanaisDigitais/Subcategoria/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "CanaisDigitais", action = "Subcategorias", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        /********************************************************************************************************/
        /*Conteudo*/
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Conteudo", // Route name
            url: "CanaisDigitais/Subcategoria/Conteudo/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "CanaisDigitais", action = "Conteudo", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Editar Conteudo", // Route name
             url: "CanaisDigitais/Subcategoria/Conteudo/Edit/{id}/{idp}",
             defaults: new { controller = "CanaisDigitais", action = "EditCont", id = UrlParameter.Optional, idp = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
        routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Deletar Conteudo", // Route name
              url: "CanaisDigitais/Subcategoria/Conteudo/Delete/{id}/{idp}",
              defaults: new { controller = "CanaisDigitais", action = "DeleteCont", id = UrlParameter.Optional, idp = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
        /********************************************************************************************************************/
        /*Rotiamento do fórum*/
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Topico", // Route name
            url: "Forum/Topicos/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Forum", action = "IndexTopicos", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Editar Topico", // Route name
            url: "Forum/Topicos/Edit/{id}/{idp}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Forum", action = "EditTopicos", id = UrlParameter.Optional, idp = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Deletar Topico", // Route name
            url: "Forum/Topicos/Delete/{id}/{idp}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Forum", action = "DeleteTopicos", id = UrlParameter.Optional, idp = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        /*********************************************************************************************************/
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Posts", // Route name
            url: "Forum/Topicos/Posts/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Forum", action = "IndexPosts", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Editar Posts", // Route name
            url: "Forum/Topicos/Posts/Edit/{id}/{idp}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Forum", action = "EditPosts", id = UrlParameter.Optional, idp = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Deletar Posts", // Route name
            url: "Forum/Topicos/Posts/Delete/{id}/{idp}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Forum", action = "DeletePosts", id = UrlParameter.Optional, idp = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        /*********************************************************************************************************/
        /*
         * Roteamento dos tipos da a genda
         */
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Agenda tipos", // Route name
           url: "Agenda/Tipos/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Agenda", action = "IndexTipos", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Editar Agenda tipos", // Route name
            url: "Agenda/Tipos/Edit/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Agenda", action = "EditTipos", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Deletar agenda tipos", // Route name
            url: "Agenda/Tipos/Delete/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Agenda", action = "DeleteTipos", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        /*******************************************************************************************************/
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

Porém quando eu acesso a http://localhost/CanaisDigitais/Subcategoria/Edit/1/10 e edito algum valor que dê um estado invalido no modelo e volte para a view ele me direciona para a url http://localhost/CanaisDigitais/EditSub

Este é o código que eu uso no controlle para retornar quando o modelo é invalido:

```
return View("Subcategoria/Edit", Modelo)
```

Alguma boa alma poderia me apontar onde estou errando?
Obs.: Uso MVC 4 e dotnet 4.0 não posso atualizar nenhum dos dois.